# How to get Form opened event (WinForm)?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have such form

```
public ManagerMainForm()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
...
}
```

So, if I run the app `MainForm` open and all is ok, but I need to add one new form as a popup.

```
public ManagerMainForm()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

           ....

            var dialog = new ValidationConfigDialog();
            dialog.ShowDialog();
...
}
```

And now this `ValidationConfigDialog` (Form) opening faster then `ManagerMainForm` and because of `ShowDialog` it's stop opening `ManagerMainForm` until I close it.

So, what I need? I would like to have like a `OnFormLoaded` event (maybe kind of callback) that notify me that `ManagerMainForm` has already completely loaded and visible and I can run another correspond process.

So, question is - How to get such kind of event or how to implement such logic, that allow to start process after form was loaded?

Comment: You should do that probably in the OnLoad event of the form

Comment: You also can add a `Timer` which open that form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a nice [MSDN page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/order-of-events-in-windows-forms?view=netcore-3.1#application-startup-and-shutdown-events) that tells you the order of events that are raised when a form is opened. The order is:

- `HandleCreated`
- `BindingContextChanged`
- `Load`
- `VisibleChanged`
- `Activated`
- `Shown`

Since your problem is that the second form is showing too early, I suggest you pick the latest event to execute the code that shows the second form. If that doesn't work for some reason, try the second latest, and so on.

Example:

```
Shown += (sender, args) => {
    var dialog = new ValidationConfigDialog();
    dialog.ShowDialog();
};
```